# Why is that $\int (-2\sin 2xdx ≠ \int( -4\sin x\cos x)dx$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

$$\sin 2x = 2\sin x \cos x \quad\text{ and }\quad -2\sin2x = -4\sin x \cos x.$$

However, when I integrate each with respect to $x$: 
$$\int (-2\sin 2x)dx=\cos 2x$$ and
$$\int( -4\sin x\cos x)dx=2\cos^2x$$

Clearly $$\cos 2x ≠ 2\cos^2x.$$

Why is this the case when $$-2\sin 2x = -4\sin x\cos x?$$

Which one am I suppose to use when integrating?

Comment: Because cos(2x) and 2cos^2(x) are the same function, up to an additive constant (which should appear anyway in every primitive).

Comment: I edit you question for convenience of the readers. Is that what you mean?

Comment: As Did said, your two integrals **are** the same, you just forgot the "constant of integration".

Comment: @Did  
What happens if it's a definite integral (hence no constant)? Depending on the upper and lower limit, I might get a different answer depending on which function I choose to integrate over, right?

Comment: For limits $(a,b)$, one would get $$\left.\cos(2x)\right|_a^b=\cos(2b)-\cos(2a)$$ and/or $$\left.2\cos^2x\right|_a^b=2\cos^2b-2\cos^2a$$ **which coincide**. (Sorry but do you understand that $$\cos(2b)-\cos(2a)=2\cos^2b-2\cos^2a$$ for every $a$ and $b$?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This show the importance of adding a constant in the Indefinite Integral, notice that 
$$∫(−2\sin2x)dx=\cos2x+C_1$$ and $$\int( -4\sin x\cos x)dx=2\cos^2x+C_2$$
On the other hand you know the trigonometric identity $$\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1$$
Indeed for the above integrals just need an aproppiate constant to verify the identity!

Comment: What happens if it's a definite integral (hence no constant)? Depending on the upper and lower limit, I might get a different answer depending on which function I choose to integrate over, right?

Comment: If you have an definite integral that is correct!

Comment: Wow, so certain definite integrals give multiple answers; genuinely never knew that before!

Comment: Its obvious that integrate a diferents functions in an fix interval give multiples answers.. don't see any new in that. I hope you're not refering to make definite integral of the same function using an identity, i wasn't reply to that....